# converting from d3 3.0 to 4.0 x axis not displaying

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have searched all over including here for an answer, but I can't seem to find anything that fixes my specific problem.

I am learning D3, but most tutorials are for 3.x.  I would prefer to use the latest version, so I have attempted to take a working 3.x tutorial I found and convert it to 4.x.  The Y Axis is visible, but the X axis ticks, X axis labels, and the line of data in the chart are not.  It looked like I just needed to change some function names, but I must have missed something.  I have try/catches just in case there's an unhandled exception, but nothing catches.  I've tried stepping through the code with Chrome, but I don't see anything obvious.

Here's the code.  Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<html>
<head><title>D3 test</title></head>

<body>

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Charting </h1>
    <p class="lead">Charting with D3</p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <style>
        .row div {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

        .line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: steelblue;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }
    </style>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            Date.prototype.addHours = function(h) {    
                this.setTime(this.getTime() + (h*60*60*1000)); 
                return this;
            }

            var parseDate = d3.utcParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S");

            function generateData()
            {
                try
                {
                    var startDate = parseDate("2016-07-15T00:00:00");
                    var currentDate = startDate;
                    var data = new Array(61);
                    for (var index = 0; index < data.length; ++index)
                    {
                        data[index] = { date: currentDate, close: Math.random() * 100 };
                        currentDate = currentDate.addHours(1);
                    }

                    return data;
                }
                catch (ex) 
                {
                    ex = ex;
                }
            }

            try{
                var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
                    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
                    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
                var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

                var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
                var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

                var line = d3.line()
                    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
                    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

                var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                  .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

                var data = generateData();

                x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
                y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "x axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(xAxis);

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "y axis")
                    .call(yAxis)
                  .append("text")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                    .attr("y", 6)
                    .attr("dy", ".71em")
                    .style("text-anchor", "end")
                    .text("Price ($)");

                svg.append("path")
                    .datum(data)
                    .attr("class", "line")
                    .attr("d", line);
            }
            catch (ex)
            {
                ex = ex;
            }
        </script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is not the version of D3 (3.x or 4.x), but your `generateData` function: all the objects have the same date (the last one).

I changed the function to this:

```
function generateData(){
                var startDate = parseDate("2016-07-15T00:00:00");
                var currentDate = startDate;
                var data = new Array(61);
                for (var index = 0; index < data.length; ++index)
                {
                    data[index] = { date: currentDate.toString(), close: Math.random() * 100 };
                    currentDate.addHours(1);
                }
                return data;
            };
```

Then, I converted the string back to dates:

```
data.forEach(function(d){
    d.date = Date.parse(d.date); 
});
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/yngdyqdr/1/

PS: in your code, there is no `addHours`. I used this one:

```
Date.prototype.addHours = function(h) {    
    this.setTime(this.getTime() + (h*60*60*1000)); 
    return this;   
};
```

Comment: Thanks!  My addHours code ( it's there at the top of the script tag ) was indeed doing as yours and changing the instance, so all of my data had the same x value.

Comment: Oh, yes, it's there!